# How to get getElementById

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

Below is the JavaScript that I used to `getElementById` but this is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
   function invoke(but)
        {
            if(but==5)
            {
                alert(document.firstChild);
                
            }
            else if(but==6)
            {
                window.location.href="index1.jsp";
            }
                
        }
       function UnBloc1()
        {
            document.getElementById("temp2").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("temp4").style.display="block";
        }
    </script>
```

and the JSP applicable is a below:

```
<%
try{
int i=0;
int temp=0, temp1=0,temp2=0, temp3=0, temp4=0;
for(i=0;i<14;i++)
               
    {
       temp=temp+1;
       temp1=temp1+1;
       temp2=temp2+1;
       temp3=temp3+1;
       temp4=temp4+1;        
       i++;
       %>
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="<%=i%>" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc<%=i%>" name="abc<%=i%>" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp1<%=i%>" id="temp1<%=i%>" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp3<%=i%>" id="temp3<%=i%>" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp4<%=i%>" id="temp4<%=i%>" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    <% }

}
catch(Exception e)
           {

out.println(e);

}
%>
```

The source code generated is as below. Here I want to know how to get the dynamic button values in `getElmentById` for button for `UnBloc()` method in JavaScript.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
    
   function invoke(but)
        {
            if(but==5)
            {
                alert("hi");
                
            }
            else if(but==6)
            {
                window.location.href="index1.jsp";
            }
                
        }
       function UnBloc1()
        {
            document.getElementById("temp2").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("temp4").style.display="block";
        }
    </script> </head>
```

```
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="1" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc1" name="abc1" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp11" id="temp11" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp31" id="temp31" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp41" id="temp41" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="3" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc3" name="abc3" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp13" id="temp13" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp33" id="temp33" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp43" id="temp43" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="5" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc5" name="abc5" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp15" id="temp15" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp35" id="temp35" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp45" id="temp45" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="7" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc7" name="abc7" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp17" id="temp17" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp37" id="temp37" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp47" id="temp47" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="9" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc9" name="abc9" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp19" id="temp19" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp39" id="temp39" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp49" id="temp49" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="11" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc11" name="abc11" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp111" id="temp111" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp311" id="temp311" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp411" id="temp411" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

    
                  
                  <tr><form name="abc" method="post" action="">
                  <td><input type="text" value="13" name="id1" id="id1"></td>
                  <td><center><input type="text" value="a" readonly="readonly" id="abc13" name="abc13" size="100"></center></td>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp113" id="temp113" onClick="invoke(5)"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer" onClick="UnBloc1()"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="temp313" id="temp313" style="border:hidden; display: none"/></td>           
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp413" id="temp413" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(6)"/>
                  
                  </td>
                  </form></tr>

      
    </table></body></html>
```

Comment: I don't see any element with ID `temp2` or `temp4`.

Comment: this is what i'm unable to get here id is id="temp4<%=i%>". i want to get it in getElementById(). how do i get it jay?

Comment: That's `temp4i`, where `i` varies. Not exactly `temp4`. Just use the `<%=i%>` in the script as you would in the HTML.

Comment: but js is not accepting it is saying like i is an invalid variable.

Comment: Generate it via JSP, so that the script have a dynamic number appending the `temp4` string.

Comment: i'm getting the dynamic values in jsp but unable to get in js. in js when i'm using temp<%=i%>, it is not atall accepting it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18004/discussion-between-rakesh-and-jay)

Comment: You may need to split the JSP `<%`...`%>` block like this: ...`getElementById("temp4%><%=i%><%");`...